# How to encode GZipEncoder.class coded JSON reponse

Tags: java, json, encode

I have a service which is being encoded with GZipEncoder.class in java restful services. Now, when I'm trying to hit and get the response. I'm getting encoded response as ���*O���4�=��鯒c[F�S��. Can anyone suggest how can I decode when I hit the API using Postman

Comment: In general, it would be a good idea for your service to respect the Accept-Encoding header in the request. Only compress the response if the request says that it's okay to do so... and make sure you specify the encoding in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer @jon Skeet. Adding `Accept-Encoding: application/gzinp, deflate` in Postman header has helped me to encode it. This is useful. ==> [#2689](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2689)